# Resultado do item da pesquisa na mesma linha separado por vírgula

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho um select que me retorna os riscos (segurança do trabalho) em várias linhas, gostaria que o item "T4.RIS_RISCO" aparecesse em uma única linha separado por vírgula, será que alguém pode me ajudar??? tenho conhecimentos básicos...

```
SELECT 
  T1.ASO_ID,
  T1.RIS_ID,
  T3.RGR_GRUPO,
  T4.RIS_RISCO
FROM
  ASO_RISCOS T1
  INNER JOIN GRUPO_RISCOS T2 ON (T1.RIS_ID = T2.RIS_ID)
  INNER JOIN RISCO_GRUPO T3 ON (T2.RGR_ID = T3.RGR_ID)
  INNER JOIN RISCOS T4 ON (T2.RIS_ID = T4.RIS_ID)
WHERE T1.ASO_ID = :ASO_ID
ORDER BY RGR_GRUPO, RIS_RISCO
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o [`list()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635575/4551469)|:

```
SELECT T1.ASO_ID, T1.RIS_ID, T3.RGR_GRUPO, LIST(T4.RIS_RISCO, ', ')
FROM
  ASO_RISCOS T1
  INNER JOIN GRUPO_RISCOS T2 ON (T1.RIS_ID = T2.RIS_ID)
  INNER JOIN RISCO_GRUPO T3 ON (T2.RGR_ID = T3.RGR_ID)
  INNER JOIN RISCOS T4 ON (T2.RIS_ID = T4.RIS_ID)
WHERE T1.ASO_ID = :ASO_ID
GROUP BY T1.ASO_ID, T1.RIS_ID, T3.RGR_GRUPO
ORDER BY RGR_GRUPO, RIS_RISCO
```

(lembre de agrupar pelos campos que estão "fora do list")